# Qt How to make QStringList non editable

Tags: qt, list, listview

My structure is like that,

```
QStringList list;
list << "Hello" << "world" << "Blah" << "Blah ;
QStringListModel *model = new QStringListModel;
model->setStringList(list);
QListView *view = new QListView(this);
view->setModel(model);
```

Now I want to make the list non editable on my GUI.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add

```
view->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
```

Answer (score 2):

Derive your model from `QStringListModel` and override [`flags()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstringlistmodel.html#flags) to clear `ItemIsEditable` flag.